# Issue with Ademco Security Keypad

Tags: home-automation, security

I bought the home with Security Ademco Vista Panel from the dealer, but the Keypad's master code is not at it's default "1234". I talked to the dealer, he gave me the Phone # of the previous owner, I tried calling, but the number wasn't subscribed like the previous owners number has been changed so. How do I get the Master code? AD2USB specific Cmd? Should I replace the chip? Or must I get a new Keypad?

I have the Keypad and AD2USB(Bridge to computer Communications).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You bought this from a dealer? Why aren't you talking to them?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'll try just they don't know the Master Code and I cannot reach the previous owner since they had changed their number.

Comment: It's still not clear what's going on. What did you buy from the dealer? And, when did the "previous owner" change the code? (The dealer is probably your best resource here.)

Comment: I bought the home with security Vista Panel. Previous owner changed the Master code while he was living there. I talked to the dealer, he gave me the Phone #, I tried calling, but the number wasn't subscribed like the previous owner number has been changed.

Comment: That's clearer, but I doubt you'll get a better answer here than what the dealer has to offer. (Sorry.)

Comment: That's clearer, but I doubt you'll get a clearer answer here than what the dealer has to offer.

Comment: No, what I am mainly asking is how can I get the Master Code, like do I need a new Keypad? Or do I need to replace the Data chip inside the Panel or?

Comment: Well, let's see if anyone has any good ideas for you.